# using SQLite database for smart device VS 2008

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, windows-ce, .net-cf-3.5

I'm developing an application for my WindowsCE packect PC(.netCF35) to read some parameters and record them in my SQLite database in Visual Studio 2008. I knew that I need to add SQLite references to my application (I had a succeed experience for my windows 7 application). So I downloaded related files from http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki and I just could add **System.Data.SQLite.dll** (I couldn't add **SQLite.Interop.102.dll** to my references). Now when I run my application, *I can't add any data to my database and it seems **cmdwrite.ExecuteNonQuery();** doesn't work correct*. I need to say my table name and structure is correct(I'm sure). You can see my code as follow:

```
SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=AMI.sqlite;Version=3;");

public bool Insert(string Meter_ID, string type, string readout, string timestamp)
    {
        sqlwrite = "INSERT INTO meters (id,type,val,timestamp) VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
        try
        {
            SQLiteCommand cmdwrite = new SQLiteCommand(sqlwrite, con);
            cmdwrite.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Meter_ID);
            cmdwrite.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", type);
            cmdwrite.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val", readout);
            cmdwrite.Parameters.AddWithValue("@timestamp", timestamp);

            con.Open();
            dbstate = "3";
            cmdwrite.ExecuteNonQuery();
            dbstate = "4";
            con.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            con.Close();
            return false;
        }
    }
Insert("123", "456", "789", "123");
```

Does anybody have any experience to work with SQLite database in WindowsCE?

Comment: I read somewhere that I can use NuGet to add corresponded references to my code, But I couldn't understand how I can use it in VS2008

Comment: There is no idea after 3 days?